# Angular 7 - Insert new dynamic component into existing module

Tags: angular, angular7

I am fairly new to Angular and I still don't understand how some things actually work.
I am trying to simulate $compile from angularJS

Is it possible to inject a dynamically created component into an existing module? Like, inject it into AppModule and then recompile everything on the fly... Or, get the list of modules which are imported by some other module (i.e. AppModule)

This is what I have:

```
@ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;
private comp: ComponentRef<any>;

private createComponentFromTemplate(template: string, modules: any = []) {
  let this_ = this;
  @Component({
    selector: 'some-tpl',
    template: template
  })
  class TmpComponent {
  }


  @NgModule({
    imports: modules, //here is the problem
    declarations: [
      TmpComponent
    ],
    exports: [
      TmpComponent
    ]
  })
  class TmpModule {
  }

  let mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(TmpModule);
  let factory = mod.componentFactories.find((c) => c.componentType === TmpComponent);
  this.comp = this.vc.createComponent(factory, 0, this.injector);
  //dynamic component is later destroyed
}
```

Problems:
This works completely fine, but **I would like to avoid generating a separate module.**
HTML code contained by "template" string can contain anything and that can be quite problematic if we use some other components/directives inside the template. The problem is solved by introducing "modules", an array of modules which should contain all needed modules in order to compile the new component properly

I need this so I can enable dynamic data processing:
Data is taken from DB via REST service
Depending on data type and service used to obtain it, different processing is performed (i.e. transform email into working email link, present list of objects in a table, etc.)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think there's an easier approach to this. Why not create a dynamic component and simply pass conditionals through a service, subscribe, and validate accordingly?

Comment: @francojay Please, elaborate with an example

Comment: Still trying to understand why you want a component that handles a lot of different functions. I would separate the components based on functionality, and throw that component into whatever module you want. When you make your API request, that's when you determine which component to use, and what data to pass through to it. It's important that your architecture is as modular as possible, allowing scalability

Comment: @francojay Main purpose of such component is to display obtained values in a table. Sometimes, a number should be shown as a currency, while in some other cases, a number is internal user ID. Both values should be shown properly on UI - currency as $value and user id as a link to user profile page. These are just some basic examples. Use-cases are various and I would like to add new "procesing functions" without having to refactor/write a bunch of code in order to accomplish a simple task such as those described  
P.S. Table is also generated on the fly (by fetching metadata from another API)

Answer (score 0):

So my thought process is that there are two ways to do it. I would ditch the way you're doing it and instead conditionally validate data in your custom component. One way is to use event emitters and pass data through the component:

Page using Dynamic Component

```
<dynamic-component [settings]="{ type: 'customType', params: { number: 1 } }"></dynamic-component>
```

Dynamic Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-component',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-component.style.scss'],
})
export class DynamicComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  settings: any

constructor() {     
  if (this.settings.type === 'customType') {
     // Handle conditional data
    }
  }
```

The other way is to handle data between services.

Service

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
sharedData: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null)
  constructor() {}
}
```

To pass the data from (any) page, inject the service into a constructor and call .next on the behavior subject.

```
constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {
  sharedService.sharedData.next({ type: 'customType', otherParam: 'foo' })
}
```

Then subscribe to the data, and validate accordingly

Dynamic Component

```
@AutoUnsubscribe()
@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-component',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-component.style.scss'],
})
export class DynamicComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

// Subscriptions
sharedSub$: Subscription
constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {     
  this.sharedSub$ = sharedService.sharedData.subscribe((data) => {
if (data.type === 'customType') {
   // Now you have the conditional data
}
  })

 ngOnDestroy() {}
}
```

@AutoUnsubscribe just a suggestion of mine, for handling memory and preventing leaks.